# Why did the Solamnic Knights choose a rose as their symbol?

Tags: dragonlance

Any other military order who chose a flower to represent their highest ranking members would be laughed at - so why did they do so?

Comment: What makes you believe they'd be laughed at?

Comment: Flowers (and plants) have [many different symbolic meanings,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_symbolism) well beyond the obvious "looks pretty and smells nice". Many of these symbolisms are well suited to the military. [Roses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_%28symbolism%29) in particular have enormous religious symbolism in Western tradition.

Comment: Maybe somthing cool would be better? Like __Grand-Dragon__ or __Grand-Wizard__? Google either of those two titles and see what hits you get. Names aren't everything.

Comment: "Any other military order who chose a flower [...] would be laughed at" I'm guessing you've never heard of the fleur-de-lis?

Answer (score 10):

The rose has a lot of [symbolic](http://www.whats-your-sign.com/rose-meaning.html) meaning throughout history.

- Love
- Honor
- Faith
- Beauty
- Balance
- Passion
- Wisdom
- Intrigue
- Devotion
- Sensuality
- Timelessness

Knights of the Rose, being the highest order, could easily want to embody a number of these symbols, such as Honor, Balance, Wisdom, Devotion, and Timelessness.

> The Order of the Rose has always been the most prestigious branch of the Knights of Solamnia. The Rose Knights provide leaders, lawgivers, and exemplars to the Solamnic Knights and the world, guiding others on the path of honor by word and deed alike.
>
> The Measure of the Rose focuses on Wisdom and Justice. [DragonLance Nexus](http://dragonlancenexus.com/lexicon/index.php?title=Knights_of_the_Rose)

Not sure what it is from originally, but the *alternate* [DragonLance Nexus](http://www.dlnexus.com/archives/kos/display.aspx?id=14096) has this to say

> Legends hold that, at the end of his Quest of Honor, Vinas Solamnus knelt in the Whitestone Glade, on Sancrist, and received the investiture by the three gods of the Knighthood, Paladine, Kiri-Jolith and Habbakhuk. **When he raised, he saw a beautiful rose of gold blowing in the spot he had been kneeling. He so decided to name the highest Order of the knighthood in this way**, to remind Solamnia of this sign of divine favour: and so Paladine took the golden rose, and gave it to King Vinas, who embossed it on his ancient plate armour, over his heart. From then on, the Grand Plate of the Rose has been the armour rightfully owned by the High Justice of the Order; sadly, in the days following the Cataclysm, it was lost.

Comment: I believe that last quote is from Knights of the Rose, #5 in the Warriors series, by Roland J. Green. I'm not sure if I have the book out of storage at home to check it or not.